# finite element method confusion why?

Tags: heat-equation, finite-element-method

In the third picture , I dont understand the circled part , add up the values in the diagonal .. How to do that ?

I dont understand how to get k13 , k14 , k21 , k22 , k33, k41 and k42 . 
As we see in the second picture , the k21 and k22 = -20 and 20 respectively , why in the third picture , the k1 and k22 become -20 and 40 ?

: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/nOiDU.jpg
  : ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/dg92C.jpg
  : ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/yijY8.jpg
  : ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/dUHUL.jpg
  : ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/c8HCV.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please format your question properly, and read the **[Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)** and **[How to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)** before posting.

Comment: We'll need a bit more context to help you out.

Comment: @SeanRoberson , what else do you need ?

Comment: Updated picture links for one.

Comment: @SeanRoberson , i am sorry i couldnt post link here . So , can you just copy the url and add h in front to get something like https://

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOiDU.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg92C.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yijY8.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUHUL.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8HCV.jpg

Comment: @SeanRoberson , all the links posted above

Answer (score 0):

For a one-dimensional FEM, interactions on the basis functions only affect certain subdivisions lf your domain. Any time you have a node that is in two different intervals, say $(a, b)$ and $(b, c)$, you need to count its contribution twice in your stiffness matrix $K$. In the example I've outlined, $b$ is a nodw lying in two subintervals, so you must consider its contribution twice.

The stiffness matrix is built by this overlaying pattern, and diagonal entries (except $k_{11}$ and $k_{nn}$) are counted twice based on the intervals the corresponding nodes lie.

Comment: Can you give one example on how to get k33 ? I still dont understand what you mean